# Post array of struct to firebase swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array with struct type

```
struct name { 
    item1: String
    item2: String
}
```

How can I upload array with this struct value to Firebase Database

Note: 
When I try to post an array with this struct value 
Xcode always give me this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData',
>   reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at
>   Price.0. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString,
>   NSDictionary, and NSArray.'

I want store the values like this

```
Price:
    0:
       item1: value
       item2: value
    1:
       item1: value
       item2: value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase can't store this type.
You can download it this way

```
Database.database().reference().child("Price").child("NUMBER").setValue(["item1" : ITEM1_VALUE, "item2" : ITEM2_VALUE])
```

Number is your count, you can implement it each time

Comment: I want store the values like this
Price:
        0:
           item1: value
           item2: value
        1:
           item1: value
           item2: value

Comment: @AbdulelahAlharabi Edit the answer, please check)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let price = [["item1":value,"item2":value],["item1":value,"item2":value]]
Database.database().reference().child("Price").updateChildValues(price)
```

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '[[String : String]]' to expected argument type '[AnyHashable : Any]'